# How can I upload a file to Solr in Windows?

Tags: windows, solr

I need to verify that text extraction is working on my Solr installation on Windows Server 2003.  All the examples I found for uploading files to Solr use curl like below.

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?&extractOnly=true"  --data-binary @tutorial.html  -H 'Content-type:text/html'
```

How can I do this in Windows?  I want to test upload a pdf and Word document then confirm I can search for words contained in the document using Solr admin page.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With the examples comes a `post.jar` (see folder `example\exampledocs` of the `apache-solr-X.X.X.zip`):

`java -jar post.jar -h`

```
This is a simple command line tool for POSTing raw data to a Solr
port.  Data can be read from files specified as commandline args,
as raw commandline arg strings, or via STDIN.
Examples:
  java -jar post.jar *.xml
  java -Ddata=args  -jar post.jar '<delete><id>42</id></delete>'
  java -Ddata=stdin -jar post.jar < hd.xml
  java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv -Dtype=text/csv -jar post.jar *.csv
  java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json -Dtype=application/json -jar post.jar *.json
  java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=a -Dtype=application/pdf -jar post.jar a.pdf
Other options controlled by System Properties include the Solr
URL to POST to, the Content-Type of the data, whether a commit
or optimize should be executed, and whether the response should
be written to STDOUT. These are the defaults for all System Properties:
  -Ddata=files
  -Dtype=application/xml
  -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update
  -Dcommit=yes
  -Doptimize=no
  -Dout=no
```

OR

The Windows PowerShell 3.0 has an `Invoke-WebRequest` command which for sure could be used for that. See [this blog post](http://rambletech.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/windows-powershell-v3-includes-command-like-wgetcurl/).

[image: Invoke-WebRequest]

Comment: I tried posting a pdf using post.jar but I get an error.  SimplePostTool:  FATAL:  Solr returned error #405 Method Not Allowed.

Comment: @John: I just tried using the standard example: started the server by `apache-solr-3.4.0\example>java -jar start.jar` and posted the pdf file with `apache-solr-3.4.0\example\exampledocs>java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=foobar -Dtype=application/pdf -jar post.jar foobar.pdf` works for me ...

Comment: I have Solr running under Tomacat if that makes a difference.  Here is the command I'm running:  java -Durl=http://localhost:8080/solr/update/extract?literal.id=addin -Dtype=application/pdf -jar post.jar addin.pdf

Comment: @John: See the Tomcat logs for errors - you'll have some for sure. The Solr webapp is not configured correctly. When starting tomcat assure that `JAVA_OPTS=-Dsolr.solr.home="...\apache-solr-3.4.0\example\solr"` points to the correct directory

Comment: Solr is starting correctly under Tomcat.  Getting an error for the attempted upload.

Comment: WARNING: The @Deprecated SolrUpdateServlet does not accept query parameters: literal.id=a
  If you are using solrj, make sure to register a request handler to /update rather then use this servlet.
  Add: <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.XmlUpdateRequestHandler" > to your solrconfig.xml

Oct 28, 2011 2:32:23 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: Error processing "legacy" update command:com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0xe3 (at char #10, byte #-1)

Comment: @John: I have `<requestHandler name="/update"                   class="solr.XmlUpdateRequestHandler">` in the config I used ... (it's the default config that comes with the 3.4.0 examples)

Comment: Think that is part of the problem as I have copied over my original solrconfig.xml with the one from Drupal since I'm using Solr for search in Drupal.  I did add in the requestHandler key and restarted Tomcat but still no luck.

Comment: @John: But your original question is answered, right? Maybe you should ask a new question on the configuration problem?

Comment: Can anyone who has succeeded in using the PowerShell cmdlet `Invoke-WebRequest` (actually aliased to `curl`) to do this please post a snippet? I keep getting 400 errors(Bad Request). Do I need to do a Put or a Post method? Can the data be passed in as `-InFile` or do I need `-Body` for that?

Comment: Sounds like I want `-Method Post` and `-Body $string_from_file` instead of the path to the file. That got me past the errors at least.

Answer (score 5):

With solr 5.0 you have to mention core name while updating the docs. So the command to post all the examples in the exampledocs will be:

> java -Dc="core_name" -jar post.jar *.xml

here replace core_name with the name of the core

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use cURL command for posting files to solr, you are required to download this utility from [cURL Home](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html). Provide the path of cURL.exe in path [environmental variable of the windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519) and then you can use the command you queried for

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?&extractOnly=true" --data-binary @"location of file/test.pdf" -H 'Content-type:application/pdf'
```

i.e. you are required to change the content type.

> Another way to post the directory to Solr is by using the 'post.jar' utility in the examples directory of the Solr - remember this utility is not for production use.

Here is the sample command.

```
   java -Ddata=files -Dtype=html -Dfiletypes=htm,html -Dauto=yes -Drecursive=yes -jar post.jar "Drive_letter:\yourpath\."
```

The above works perfectly with Solr 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Using Solr 6.1 on Windows I was able to recursively index a folder using the SimplePostTool from solr-core-x.y.z.jar like so:

```
java -classpath C:\Solr\solr-6.1.0\dist\solr-core-6.1.0.jar -Dauto=yes -Dc=yourcorename -Ddata=files -Drecursive=yes org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool C:\Solr\solr-6.1.0\docs
```

You will need to replace "C:\Solr\solr-6.1.0\" with your solr folder, specify the correct version number for solr-core-6.1.0.jar, set the folder to the location of file you want to index and ensure the core exists already.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this using Powershell, run following command:

```
$header =  @{"Content-type"="text/plain"; "charset"="utf-8"};

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:8983/solr/YOUR_CORE_NAME/update/csv -Headers $header -InFile "C:\data.csv" -Method Post
```

Answer (score 1):

Can have following options -

- Fire URL from browser using the stream.file (stream.url for remote urls) parameter which points to the file on the local file system e.g. [sample_url](http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?stream.file=path_to_file&literal.id=5&commit=true)
- Install cgywin/curl for windows, which will help you to fire these urls.
- Write a short [program using Solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Sending_documents_to_Solr) (or any other solr client) to post these documents.

Comment: A little addition: CURL is available for windows. There is also libCURL, which allows you to embed CURL operations in dozens of major languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Firefox Poster Plugin.. I tried couple of downloads and they worked fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

> C:\Java\Libs\apache-solr-4.0.0-BETA\example>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update?commit=true&stream.contentType=text/csv;charset=utf-8
>   &stream.file=C:/Java/Libs/apache-solr-4.0.0-BETA/example/exampledocs/listado_talleres_new.csv"

Comment: It seems that you are unduly making assumptions about the system. Could you edit your answer to be more generally applicable? - Also you do not specify what your answer is supposed to do, could you add at least a short explanation?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows I use this cоmmand:

```
java -classpath %SOLR_HOME%\dist\solr-core-6.5.1.jar -Dauto=yes -Dc=books -Ddata=files -Drecursive=yes org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool c:\apache-solr-6.5.1\server\solr\books\data\index\*.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Through command line first navigate to the exampledocs folder of Solr and execute the below command

```
D:\solr-7.5.0\example\exampledocs>java -Dc=onlycorename -Dtype=application/json -jar post.jar books.json
```

Alternatively, From the example folder execute the below command

```
D:\Open Source Servers\solr-7.5.0\example>java -Dc=films -Dtype=application/xml -jar exampledocs/post.jar exampledocs/*.xml
```