# 'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, solr

I'm working on apache solr 5,when I'm trying to execute  `$ bin/post -c gettingstarted example/exampledocs/*.json`, I am getting warning like

> 'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

It's working when I execeute  `bin\solr create -c test`.

Please help me out, I'm new to solr concepts.

Thanks

Comment: Refer this answer the problem seems to be same [http://stackoverflow.com/a/36890331/2114781](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36890331/2114781)

Answer (score 12):

the issue is not with Solr, its with the command you are typing. Linux directories are traversed using '/' while windows with '\'. 
Assuming your OS is windows, from your current working directory (which is the solr folder in this example) **bin\solr** is a valid path, hence that executes. 
however **bin/solr** being an invalid path fails to execute.
Hence your first command should work from the same location in Unix/Linux systems, second one in Windows

EDIT: I just downloaded the solr installer as zip from the solr site. The post file is indeed a shell script, which is why you are unable to execute it on windows. (my understanding was that .gzips were linux installers and .zip for windows always, which is clearly not the case here.)

What you probably can do is check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14824950/1304575) and follow the approach mentioned there. Hopefully that will get you up and running.

Hope it helps!

Comment: bin\post' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. When i execute command like this ,   bin\post -c sample example\exampledocs\*.json

Comment: kindly mention what is your current directory location.
Also you can move inside the bin folder and then execute the program to eliminate the directory issue.

Comment: C:\Users\Nagendra\Desktop\solr\bin>post -c sample example\exampledocs\*.json

'post' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: and you are sure that you are using the correct installation (depending on the OS), and that the file is there in the location, and that its a valid batch file?

Comment: yeah,and in bin folder there is a file name :'post' and type: 'file'.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is too late to answer this question, but it might be helpful to others who face this issue.

`bin/post` exists only as Unix shell script. Internally it uses a Java program `SimplePostTool`, which is present in the jar : `example\exampledocs\post.jar`. To use `post` in Windows, run the command `java -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar` instead of `bin\post`. For example, `post -h` can be run as : `java -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar -h`.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to copy all the file with extension .json to your core named "gettingstarted" using post tool. But post tool does not supported for windows.
Please visit following link. Hope this will help.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Post+Tool#PostTool-Windows